# MD5 hashing is same in IOS and windows but different in java

Tags: java, c#, ios, hash, md5

I am getting the same value for IOS and Winows md5 hashing but in the case of java i am getting a different value,

IOS code for md5 hashing

```
- (NSString*)md5HexDigest:(NSString*)input
{
    NSData *data = [input dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding];
    unsigned char result[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_MD5([data bytes], (CC_LONG)[data length], result);

    NSMutableString *ret = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH*2];
    for(int i = 0; i<CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
        [ret appendFormat:@"%02x",result[i]];
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Windows Code for md5 hashing

```
private static string GetMD5(string text)
        {
            UnicodeEncoding UE = new UnicodeEncoding();
            byte[] hashValue;
            byte[] message = UE.GetBytes(text);

            MD5 hashString = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            string hex = "";

            hashValue = hashString.ComputeHash(message);
            foreach (byte x in hashValue)
            {
                hex += String.Format("{0:x2}", x);
            }
            return hex;
        }
```

Java Code for md5 hasing:  Tried with  UTF-8,16,32 , but not maching with the IOS and Windows

```
 public String MD5(String md5)  {
   try {

       String dat1 = md5.trim();
        java.security.MessageDigest md = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        byte[] array = md.digest(dat1.getBytes("UTF-16"));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
          sb.append(Integer.toHexString((array[i] & 0xFF) | 0x100).substring(1,3));
       }
        System.out.println("Digest(in hex format):: " + sb.toString());
        return sb.toString();
    } catch (java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    }
   catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e)
   {
   }
    return null;
}
```

thanks

Comment: What if you use `UTF-16LE`?

Comment: Does your weird `Integer.toHexString()` code actually give correct results?

Comment: UTF-16LE worked , thanks Kayaman.

Comment: @Kayaman Just curious: why does making use of  `UTF-16LE` work here? What was wrong with the existing code by OP? What is the difference, other words? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Unheilig Using just `UTF-16` puts the BOM (0xFEFF or 0xFFFE) in the beginning, to specify the endianness. Using `UTF-16BE` or `UTF-16LE` explicitly leaves the BOM out (apparently). Unicode is a b*tch.

Comment: @Kayaman So, which other encoding representation other than `Unicode` would you prefer the most for MD5?

Comment: UTF-8 is the best for interchange, it does not suffer from endian-ness since  the byte order is specified for all implementations and it is the same on-the-wire. There is no BOM. Note that for emoji and certain other plane 1 characters two UTF-16 code units are necessary. unicode is a 21-bit encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a short overview what `getBytes()` returns related to the specified character set (all credits go to @Kayaman)

```
"123".getBytes("UTF-8")   :                31 32 33 
"123".getBytes("UTF-16")  : FE FF 00 31 00 32 00 33 
"123".getBytes("UTF-16LE"):       31 00 32 00 33 00 
"123".getBytes("UTF-16BE"):       00 31 00 32 00 33
```

It shows that the BOM is added only if the endianness is not specified. Then it depends on your architecture if `LE` or `BE` is used.